# why sql query giving error unknown column to an alias

Tags: mysql, grafana

Why is this sql query giving error ?

```
SELECT
  dt_created AS "time",
  humidity,
  ((temp* 1.8) + 32) AS temp_f,
  (-42.379 + 2.04901523 * temp_f + 10.14333127*humidity - .22475541* temp_f * humidity - .00683783 * temp_f* temp_f - .05481717*humidity*humidity + .00122874 * temp_f * temp_f*humidity + .00085282 * temp_f*humidity*humidity - .00000199 * temp_f * temp_f*humidity*humidity)  AS  "Feels Like"
FROM particle_photon
WHERE
  dt_created BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1572739408) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1572825808)
ORDER BY dt_created;
```

The error is `Error 1054: Unknown column 'temp_f' in 'field list'`
But I do have `temp_f` declared in alias !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `alias` as part of your `columns`. You need to put this in `subquery` and do necessary computations.

```
select time
    , humidity
    , temp_f
    , (-42.379 + 2.04901523 * temp_f + 10.14333127*humidity - .22475541* temp_f * humidity - .00683783 * temp_f* temp_f - .05481717*humidity*humidity + .00122874 * temp_f * temp_f*humidity + .00085282 * temp_f*humidity*humidity - .00000199 * temp_f * temp_f*humidity*humidity)  AS  "Feels Like"
from (select
      dt_created as "time",
      humidity,
      ((temp* 1.8) + 32) AS temp_f
    from particle_photon
    where
      dt_created between FROM_UNIXTIME(1572739408) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1572825808)
    order by dt_created) as t1
```

**or**

replace `temp_f` with `((temp* 1.8) + 32)` if you don't want to use a `subquery`.

Comment: perfect except in my select query had date and time in `dt_created` which is my bad I aliased it as `time`

Comment: oh, i see, you can also specify the table `alias` on your time `t1.time`